# Compare host output to print message

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script where i will give an IP as an argument. If the IP is not valid I want to print to screen a message.If the IP is valid I print the hostname.

```
host $1 | cut -d' ' -f5
```

This is my code if the IP is valid. I don't know hot to compare the output if it's not valid to print the corresponding message

Comment: The first step is to define precisely what you mean by a "valid IP". The second step is to write code that checks whether an IP meets that precise definition of "valid IP". The third step is to add a conditional and use your newly written program as the condition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
if host=$(host "$1" 2>/dev/null); then  # ignore stderr
    echo "$host"
else
    echo "$1 is not a valid host"
fi
```

If you want to display the error output of `host` in the else part, then:

```
if host=$(host "$1" 2>&1); then  # merge stdout and stderr
    echo "$host"
else
    echo "$1 is not a valid host, error=$host"
fi
```

Comment: It worked but can you explain me what 2>/dev/null does?

Comment: @andrikoulas I think it dumps the error messages to [`/dev/null/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119650).